# Convergence to approximate fixed points of firmly nonexpansive maps in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T: H\to H$ be a firmly nonexpansive mappings i.e. for all $x,y\in H,$ $$\|Tx-Ty\|^2\leq\langle x-y,Tx-Ty\rangle.$$ An element $x_0$ is an approximate fixed point of $T$ if $\|T x_0-x_0\|<\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$.

The question is if there are theorems that guarantee convergence of the iteration $x_{n+1}=Tx_n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ to approximate fixed points of the operator $T$?

Comment: Does "firmly nonexpansive" mean $\|Tx-Ty\|\le L\|x-y\|$, where $L<1$ ? If so, then the Banach fixed point theorem guarantees that $(x_n)$ tends to a fixed point.

Comment: I added the definition to the question. So a firmly nonexpanisve map is necessarily nonexpansive, i.e. $\|Tx-Ty\|\leq\gamma\|x-y\|, \gamma \leq 1$ but not necessarily contractive.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. What is $\epsilon$? And don't say it's a small number.

Comment: If $T$ has at least one fixed point, then your iteration will converge to a fixed point of $T$. Even if $\textrm{Fix} T=\varnothing$, you may find an approximate one if the "Minimal displacement vector" has norm $\leq \epsilon$. See also the notions of "Asymptotically regular" and "cosmic convergence." Heinz Bauschke does a good job of rounding up references on this subject in his papers and his book.  Preprints: https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/97.pdf https://people.ok.ubc.ca/bauschke/Research/111.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Browder, Petryshyn, Krasnoselskii, and Mann are some big names in this field of study specifically for nonexpansive mappings.  I've given some references (with links that you may need academic access to view) for you to investigate.  The last one listed is specifically regarding firmly nonexpansive mappings.

"THE SOLUTION BY ITERATION OF NONLINEAR
FUNCTIONAL EQUATIONS IN BANACH SPACES" by Browder and Petryshyn
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2c84/ba99f80ef6240ec34ff649a97c06637fff20.pdf

"On the asymptotic behavior of iterates of nonexpansive mappings in Hilbert space" by Pazy https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03007669

"Convergence of Krasnoselskii-Mann iterations of nonexpansive operators" by Reich and Zaslavski https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895717700002144

"Existence and Approximation of Fixed Points of Firmly Nonexpansive-Type Mappings in Banach Spaces" by Kohsaka and Takahashi https://doi.org/10.1137/070688717

Comment: Thank you. That's pointing me in the right direction.